$_GET returns empty array after clicking on a link with passed values
When I click the second link with the embedded values in it, the script that has to access them returns an empty array. In that script I am just using $_GET to test and see what is passed.
I also know that the code has a lot of vulnerabilities in it, I am not planning to get this to be posted online, I just want to add some demo functionalities.
Here is my code:
<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querySubjs))
    {
        $subjectStatus = is_null($row["subject_status"]) ? $subjectStatusDisplay = "Незададен" : $row["subject_status"];
        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>$row[subject_name]</td>
                <td>$subjectStatus</td>
                <td>
        ";
        $subj = $row["subject_name"];
        $getTeachs = "SELECT * FROM teacher INNER JOIN student_teacher_subject ON teacher.ID = student_teacher_subject.teacher_ID
        WHERE student_ID = '$getResultsStd[ID]' AND subject_name = '$subj'";
        $queryTeachs = mysqli_query($mysqli, $getTeachs);
        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryTeachs))
        {   
            echo "{$row1['email']}";
        }
        echo "</td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='teacher' class='teacher-input'> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href='#'>Редактирай</a>
            <a href='process_std_teach_subj.php?email=".$getResultsStd["email"]."&subject=".$subj."' class='add'>Добави</a>
        </td>
        </tr>";
        
    }

?>

$getResultsStd is an array that is set after making a query to get all the data about a student. It is defined.
This is the code in the script that the anchor is linked to:
$m = $_GET["email"];
echo $m;

For the test I tried the email only, but it throws an error:

Undefined array key "email"


Check the generated link in your HTML <a> attribute to ensure that the email and subject parameters are properly being appended to the URL. You can also try var_dump($_GET) the full $_GET array at the top of your process_std_teach_subj.php file to help identify if you are getting any data at all.

I tried that and it throws an empty array. When I hover on the link in the page it shows properly bounded values.

Maybe there's a redirect in your server config and it's not preserving the query parameters.

Use DevTools  Network tab to see what's being sent when following the link.

So when you click on the link, does the browser location change to the expected URL with the query parameters?

That’s the other problem. It doesn’t. It just displays the result in the console tab in the dev tools.

And what exactly does that mean? What is "the result"? If the request is actually happening, but the browser address bar doesn't change, then (unless you were linking to a script that gives a 204 No Content response) that would probably mean, you got some JavaScript involved that captures this link click, and makes an AJAX request in the background.

Exactly, the result is an empty array if I try to return the values from $_GET. I have an AJAX request that gets the value from the “teacher” input field and makes POST request to the script. It works. But the other values are not passed.

I just found out that when I entirely remove the JS code with the AJAX request, GET returns everything just fine...
